# How to place a market futures order with take profit and stop loss on Binance API Python?

Tags: python, binance

I want to place a market long order with take profit and stop loss and a short position the same way. I need to use leverage and isolated mode. I have configured the leverage, isolated mode, how much margin I want to use, and the quantity. I have a problem understanding the Binance docs. Can somebody provide me the code I need to use to place a market long order with take profit and stop loss and a short position?

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you can't do it in one order via Binance API

You need to place 3 orders in order to implement this:

1. Initial order to open your SHORT or LONG position (type: "BUY" for long; type: "SELL" for short)
2. TAKE-PROFIT order
3. STOP order

This is the way that Binance handles your margin order with both stop-loss and take profit

It can be done like this for SHORT position in python (if you need to open LONG instead of SHORT just change "BUY" to "SELL" and "SELL" to "BUY":

```
from binance import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
quantity = 0.001
symbol = "BTCUSDT"
tp_price = 22800
sl_price = 22000

client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="SELL", type="MARKET", quantity=quantity)
client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="BUY", type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", quantity=quantity, stopPrice=tp_price)
client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side="BUY", type="STOP_MARKET", quantity=quantity, stopPrice=sl_price)
```